# Bring parent component in focus when button on child component is clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have a web app where I am showing multiple cards one after another. My web app is primarily used on mobile devices. When the app loads all cards are loaded at once and the screen scrolls to the last card. Each card has a button at the bottom. I want to bring a card in focus when someone clicks on a button present at the bottom of the card. By "focus" I mean to bring the header of the card at the top of the screen and then the content of the same card.

I am using the below approach where I am creating a ref hook and attaching it to the card. I created a function `bringCardIntoFocus` that brings the HTML element with this ref in focus. Then pass this function to the child component which renders the button. When the button is clicked, I am calling the function to bring the card in focus.

```
const cardRef = useRef(null);
    const bringCardIntoFocus = () => {
        cardRef.current.focus();
    };
    const Card = () => {
      return (
        <Message
        ref={cardRef}
        content={
            <FlexCol>
                <CardHeader />
                <CardBody />
                <CardFooter focusCard={() => bringCardIntoFocus()}/>
            </FlexCol>
        }
      />
      ); 
};
const CardFooter = ({bringCardIntoFocus}) => {
    const handleClick = () => {
        bringCardIntoFocus();
    }

    return(
        <FlexCol>
            <button onclick={() => handleClick()}>
                Open card
            </button>
        </FlexCol>
    );
}
```

Now, there are two errors which I see:

1. When the app loads I am getting:

> react_devtools_backend.js:2430 Warning: Function components cannot be
> given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use
> React.forwardRef()?

2. When I click on "Open Card" button

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

The above error refers to line `cardRef.current.focus()`

Comment: What component library are you using? Or if you wrote the code for that yourself, could you include that code in the question so we can help you better? `Message` doesn't appear to forward ref, which is causing the `cardRef` never to be set.

Comment: `Message` component is a custom component.

Comment: Can you include the code for it? That's where you need to add `forwardRef` so you can pass the ref through